# How do I initialize a Counter from a list of key/initial counts pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, counter, python-internals

If I have a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs, I can quickly initialize a dictionary like this:

```
>>> data = [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2) ]
>>> dict(data) 
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I would like to do the same with a `Counter` dictionary; but how? Both the constructor and the `update()` method treat the ordered pairs as keys, not key-value pairs:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(data)
Counter({('a', 1): 1, ('b', 2): 1})
```

The best I could manage was to use a temporary dictionary, which is ugly and needlessly circuitous:

```
>>> Counter(dict(data))
Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Is there a proper way to directly initialize a `Counter` from a list  of `(key, count)` pairs? My use case involves reading lots of saved counts from files (with unique keys).

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit." Why should your list be treated differently from other iterables just because it is in a form that *could* be converted to a `dict`?

Comment: I don't want special treatment, I want a different initialization path.

Comment: If you are really processing "lots of saved counts from files" you probably should go `pandas` or `numpy` (structured arrays). I don't know what sizes we're talking here but at some point the memory benefits (and dtype-specific implementation of operations) of homogeneous arrays will come in handy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would just do a loop:

```
for obj, cnt in [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2) ]:
    counter[obj] = cnt
```

You could also just call the parent `dict.update` method:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [ ('a', 1), ('b', 2) ]
>>> c = Counter()
>>> dict.update(c, data)
>>> c
Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Lastly, there isn't anything wrong with your original solution:

```
Counter(dict(list_of_pairs))
```

The expensive part of creating dictionaries or counters is hashing all of the keys and doing periodic resizes.  Once the dictionary is made, converting it to a Counter is very cheap about as fast as a dict.copy().  The hash values are reused and the final Counter hash table is pre-sized (no need for resizing).

Comment: Note: Great solutions but only work for a list of keys are already unique. If you have something like `[ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 4) ]` you need to loop over all the pairs to get the totals I think, no? The OP does note qualify that the keys in the list are, in fact, unique or not.

Comment: @dawg The first solution is easily adapted to duplicate keys with ``counter[obj] += cnt``.

Comment: Yes, that is my point: If you want totals you must loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Elements are counted from an iterable or initialized from another mapping (or counter)

So it's a *No*, you need to convert it to mapping and then initialize `Counter`. And *Yes* when you initialized with `dict` it was the right move.

**UPDATE**

I agree that @RaymondHettinger code looks good, and actually it's faster

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters
a=[(choice(ascii_letters), i) for i in range(100)]
```

Tested with Python 3.6.1 and IPython 6

Initialization with `dict`:

```
%%timeit
c1=Counter(dict(a))
```

Output

```
12.1 µs ± 342 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Update with `dict.update()`

```
%%timeit    
c2=Counter()
dict.update(c2, a)
```

Output:

```
7.21 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hmm, indeed that does not look encouraging. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of keys in the `(key, value)` pairs are already unique -- no duplicates -- you can use Raymond Hettinger's [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43825040/298607).

Beware though you only get the last value for any given key if there are duplicate keys:

```
>>> data=[ ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 4) ]
>>> c=Counter()
>>> dict.update(c, data)
>>> c
Counter({'b': 4, 'a': 3})      # note 'a' and 'b' are only the last value...
```

Same with `dict`:

```
>>> Counter(dict(data))
Counter({'b': 4, 'a': 3})
```

But [Counters](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are most often used to count totals including of duplicates. If you want the sum of 'a' and 'b' entries, you need to loop over all the pairs:

```
>>> c=Counter()
>>> for k, v in data:
...    c[k]+=v
... 
>>> c
Counter({'b': 6, 'a': 4})        # the sum of the 'k' entries given 'v'
```